# Get Child Element of Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, youtube-data-api

I'm currently trying to retrieve data about uploaded videos on a Youtube channel using the Youtube Data API. I'm using PHP and the given data by google is JSON.

I've written the code according to the instructions from https://www.codewall.co.uk/how-to-read-json-file-using-php-examples/. As an example I simply use the Youtube channel of MrBeast.

My code looks like this:

```
// Get the contents of the JSON file 
$strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("$url");
// Convert to array 
$array = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);
// var_dump($array); // print array

echo $array["kind"];
```

See [Screenshot of the given API Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4owJ.png)

Now the problem: I can only address and display "kind", "etag", "nextPageToken", but not data inside / children of "items", like "publishedAt" or "title".

How can I retrieve this data? Or is there a better way to get the data out of JSON?

Comment: `items` is just an array, what’s stopping you from accessing it like one…? `$array["items"][0]["etag"]`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `foreach($array ->items as $item)` to iterate over the "items".
then:
access the fields using `$item->kind` or `$item->etag`.